# JavaScript CORS error when uploading files with Axios

Tags: reactjs, flask, file-upload, axios, cors

I am developing a web application with Flask on the backend and React and Redux on the frontend. 
I want to add a "Change Profile Picture" option to the profile page but whenever I make a post request with axios to my `/api/user/upload_image/` route, i get the following errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/user/update_image' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
PATCH http://localhost:5000/api/user/update_image net::ERR_FAILED
```

Which is weird becuase I have set up my CORS wrapper in my Flask app like so:

```
self.cors = CORS(self.app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

which should allow requests to /api/ from all origins.

I also tried to do the same thing with Postman and it worked like a charm - uploaded the file and saved it to `/server/public/profile_pictures/`

When i try to upload regular JSON text from my react application it works as well. It bugs out on file uploads only.

Here is the JSX for the input + the event handler

```
<label>
    Change Profile Picture
    <input onChange={(e) => {
        this.setState({image: e.target.files[0]})}
    } type="file" name="image" />
</label>
```

Then i have a submit button which dispatches the following action with `this.state.image` as a parameter:

```
export const updateImage = (file) => {
return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const formData = {
        user_id: getState().currentUser.user.user_id,
        auth_key: getState().currentUser.auth_key,
        image: file
    }
    Axios.patch("http://localhost:5000/api/user/update_image", formData, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        dispatch({type: UPDATE_IMAGE, payload: response.data})
    })
}
```

I tried using the built in `formData` method to create the JS object too but that was no good either.

Finally here is the python method which is called when the `/api/user/update_image` route is hit:

```
def update_image(self, request):   
    image = request.files['image']
    data = request.params

    image.save("./public/profile_pictures/user_p_picture_id_"+data['user_id']+".jpg")
    fsql.update("""UPDATE users SET profile_picture = %s WHERE user_id = %s""", ("/public/profile_pictures/user_p_picture_id_"+data['user_id']+".jpg", data['user_id']))

    return jsonify({
        "error_code" : "200", 
        "error_message" : "Success"
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved this about a week and a half ago but I checked the status today.

So the solution was to make a few changes to my config parameter and CORS parameters. Here is the configs i am using right now:

```
config = {
    'ORIGINS': [
        'http://localhost:3000',  # React
        'http://127.0.0.1:3000',  # React
    ],
    'SECRET_KEY': '...' #secret key

    self.cors = CORS(self.app, resources={
        r'/api/*': {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": config["ORIGINS"],
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": True,
            'supports_credentials': True
        },
    },
    supports_credentials = True,
    expose_headers = "*"
)

self.app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = r'/*' # Change this to only the folder you want to save images to
self.app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024 # Change this according to your file size
```

This solved my CORS and file transport issues.

I really hope this helps someone. The CORS docs on flask-cors do not cover everything in regards to file uploading and session storage so we kind of have to solve the errors without knowing how everything works - like trying to solve a puzzle with missing pieces.

HMU in messages if you have any good tools for CORS in flask which are well documented and have a community around them.